# How to mutate a property within a stenciljs component without triggering watch

Tags: stenciljs

I have a component with a viewport property. I want to listen for changes to  this property, do some calculations and reflect a  possibly changed value back to the property. My first attempt looked something like this:

```
class MyComponent {
  @Prop()
  viewport: ViewportData

  @Watch('viewport)
  viewportChanged(newValue: ViewportData, oldValue:ViewportData) {
    ... do some calculations

    // Reflect value back as property
    this.viewport = computedViewport;
  }
}
```

This results in a stack overflow because reflecting the value back triggers another call to the watch function. I could prevent it by having a flag saying if this is an internal change or not. Something like this:

```
class MyComponent {
  internalViewportChange = false;

  @Prop()
  viewport: ViewportData

  @Watch('viewport)
  viewportChanged(newValue: ViewportData, oldValue:ViewportData) {
    if (this.internalViewportChange) {
      this.internalViewportChange = false;
      return;
    }

    ... do some calculations

    // Reflect value back as property
    this.internalViewportChange = true;
    this.viewport = computedViewport;
  }
}
```

I don't like this approach. And is looking for something better. This problem could normally be solved by using getters and setters and a private variable keeping the actual state:

```
class MyComponent {
  private _viewport: ViewportData

  get viewport() {
    return this._viewport;
  }

  set viewport() {
    ... do some calculations

    // Reflect value back as property
    this.viewport = computedViewport;
  }
}
```

However, using Stenciljs the getters and setters are autogenerated. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably break the two-way prop setting, and 
create a unidirectional data flow, and emit events instead. Something like:

```
class MyComponent
  @Event() viewportChanged: EventEmitter;
  @Prop() viewport: ViewportData;
  @State() _computedViewport: ViewportData;

  @Watch('viewport') onViewportChanged(newValue) {
    // do calculations
    this._computedViewport = computedViewport;
    this.viewportChanged.emit(this._computedViewport);
  }
```

Internally, you'd only work on `_computedViewport`, and the public `viewportProp` is only there for users to update themselves. Ostensibly you could also expose a `@Method()` that does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I do today. I just wanted to explore the possibilities of using properties since accessing properties on an custom elements before they are resolved works (undefined) while methods that are missing throws.